# Extract Marketing Cloud Users Information in a CSV File

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-extract

How can I extract all information of my users like username, rules and BUs access, but I heard that action it's only possible using API?

I'm not a tecnical user. I searched for information on how to achieve this goal but didn't find anything.

Comment: Without APi access you have to go through and admin panel and and copy it out manually. A real exercise in pain

Comment: do you know SQL? you may be able to query for this.

Comment: I Searched for a Data View in help portal, but I am not finding anything.